# nginx always starts at boot time

Tags: apache, nginx

I'm running ubuntu 16.10. If there's no rc.d script starting nginx, why does it start everytime I boot my machine? How can keep  nginx from starting at boot time? I have both Apache and nginx but I use Apache the most and I always have to stop nginx manually and then start Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using upstart

```
sudo service nginx status
sudo service --status-all
```

Using systemd

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
sudo systemctl disable nginx
```